# ¿Cómo darle forma a una imagen en React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

¿cómo podría darle forma a una imagen en React Native ,  he estado  buscando la forma de que una imagen se vea de esa forma, Su marco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tal y como se ve igual está imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he estado buscando con SVG pero no encuentro la forma de poder hacer esto, de poder darle forma a esa imagen

Comment: Quieres dibujar la forma o formar la imagen?

Comment: @milmal la imagen como tal viene cuadrada, desde el back entonces necesito darle esa forma como en el ejemplo ^

Comment: Creo que es más fácil recortar la imagen en tu computadora y usar el formato png en lugar de formarla con css

Comment: @milmal ah si claro que es más facil, pero no es la mejor opción son muchas imagenes que voy a estar manejando :p y quien sabe en que momento puede cambiar esa imagen para que quede así. en Web es más facil, pues ya lo he hecho así como está, pero en Native (no he logrado jeje)